# POWER(@variable,2) SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a number like `8.32596e+010` when I try to do  `POWER(@variable,2)` it says there is a floating point error, How do you fix this??

Comment: +1 migrate to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following T-SQL works for me, in SQL Server 2008:

```
declare @x float
declare @y float
set @x = 8.32596e+010
set @y = POWER(@x,2)
print @y
```

> 6.93216e+021

Check that you're declaring all variables as floats (or floating-point types).